# How to filter the full Response in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application, I have a legacy HTML minification attribute to remove whitespace that uses regular expressions. It works, except for when it doesn't because the markup contains a `textarea` or `pre` where the whitespace needs to be preserved.

After spending the last two days reading through countless questions on SO and their answers about how to do the minification using anything, I've settled on using the HtmlAgilityPack. Using LINQPad, I pieced together the code that, as far as I can tell right now, produces exactly what I want:

```
var html = GetHtml();
var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

document.LoadHtml(html);

var spans = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(
    d =>
        d.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element
        && d.Name == "span").SelectMany(
    d => d.ChildNodes.Where(
        cn => cn.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)).ToList();

//  Some spans have content that needs to be trimmed.
foreach (var span in spans) {
    span.InnerHtml = span.InnerHtml.Trim();
}

var nodes = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(
    d =>
        (d.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text
        && d.InnerText.Trim().Length == 0)
        || (d.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Comment
        && d.InnerText.Trim() != "<!DOCTYPE html>")).Select(
    d => d).ToList();

foreach (var node in nodes) {
    node.Remove();
}

using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
    document.Save(stream);

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
        reader.ReadToEnd().Dump();
    }
}
```

So, since this produced the result I want in LINQPad, I copied it over into my attribute, but that's where I quickly discovered it wouldn't be so easy. Because the `Response.Filter` writes in chunks, I end up with a big mess if the response is larger than a single chunk.

From what I understand I need to capture the full response from the filter, then remove the whitespace with the code above, and then write that back to the filter. Unfortunatelly, I'm a bit confused on how to approach that whole process. I know how to capture the full stream from the chunks, but after that I have no idea what to do. I ask for any and all assistance on how to complete what I want to happen. Thanks in advance!

Here's the attribute and stream classes as they exist right now. I'll be honest, I don't quite know if certain pieces of the code are necessary at all... Like I said earlier, this is legacy code and has been around for at least five years in some variation.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
internal sealed class MinifyHtmlAttribute :
    ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuted(
        ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
        if (filterContext != null
            && !filterContext.IsChildAction) {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter = new MinifyHtmlStream(filterContext.HttpContext);
        }
    }
}

internal sealed class MinifyHtmlStream :
    MemoryStream {
    private readonly HttpContextBase Context;
    private readonly Stream Stream;

    public MinifyHtmlStream(
        HttpContextBase httpContextBase) {
        Context = httpContextBase;
        Stream = httpContextBase.Response.Filter;
    }

    public override void Write(
        byte[] buffer,
        int offset,
        int count) {
        var source = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        if (Context.Response.ContentType == "text/html") {
            var document = new HtmlDocument();

            document.LoadHtml(source);

            var spans = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(
                d =>
                    d.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element
                    && d.Name == "span").SelectMany(
                d => d.ChildNodes.Where(
                    cn => cn.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)).ToList();

            //  Some spans have content that needs to be trimmed.
            foreach (var span in spans) {
                span.InnerHtml = span.InnerHtml.Trim();
            }

            var nodes = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(
                d =>
                    (d.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text
                    && d.InnerText.Trim().Length == 0)
                    || (d.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Comment
                    && d.InnerText.Trim() != "<!DOCTYPE html>")).Select(
                d => d).ToList();

            foreach (var node in nodes) {
                node.Remove();
            }

            document.Save(Stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution that I'm happy with. I added a `MemoryStream` to buffer all of the chunks, then did the minification on it, and finally passed it back to the filter. Performance of the parsing and minification is fine to me, but my application is for internal use with a low amount of users. Here's the final code I've come up with:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
internal sealed class MinifyHtmlAttribute :
    ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuted(
        ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
        if (filterContext == null
            || filterContext.IsChildAction) {
            return;
        }

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter = new MinifyHtmlStream(filterContext.HttpContext);
    }
}

internal sealed class MinifyHtmlStream :
    MemoryStream {
    private readonly MemoryStream BufferStream;
    private readonly HttpContextBase Context;
    private readonly Stream FilterStream;

    public MinifyHtmlStream(
        HttpContextBase httpContextBase) {
        BufferStream = new MemoryStream();
        Context = httpContextBase;
        FilterStream = httpContextBase.Response.Filter;
    }

    public override void Flush() {
        BufferStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        if (Context.Response.ContentType != "text/html") {
            BufferStream.CopyTo(FilterStream);

            return;
        }

        var document = new HtmlDocument();

        document.Load(BufferStream);

        var spans = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(
            d =>
                d.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element
                && d.Name == "span").SelectMany(
            d => d.ChildNodes.Where(
                cn => cn.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)).ToList();

        //  Some spans have content that needs to be trimmed.
        foreach (var span in spans) {
            span.InnerHtml = span.InnerHtml.Trim();
        }

        var nodes = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(
            d =>
                (d.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text
                && d.InnerText.Trim().Length == 0)
                || (d.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Comment
                && d.InnerText.Trim() != "<!DOCTYPE html>")).Select(
            d => d).ToList();

        foreach (var node in nodes) {
            node.Remove();
        }

        document.Save(FilterStream);
    }

    public override void Write(
        byte[] buffer,
        int offset,
        int count) {
        BufferStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with TextWriter instead of stream . Then using replace method remove the whitespaces with string.empty then save the document.

Comment: I could do that, but I imagine it will give me the same result I'm trying to avoid from the regular expressions, mainly that it will strip out whitespace that actually needs to be preserved like the content of `textarea` or `pre` elements. By parsing the HTML I can find the whitespace nodes, remove them, and then return the minified HTML back. Coincidentally the code I have finds the whitespace nodes, and ignores whitespace in `textarea` and `pre` tags because it's not an actual node, so it does exactly what I want.